# How to persist UserData of Element in JAXB Unmarshal?

Tags: jaxb

I unmarshal the Document to object as below.
Before that, when parsing XML, use setUserData to store location information for each element.

```
class MyJaxbAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, SubObject> {}
    @Override
    public UnattendComponent unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Node node = (Node) v; // ElementNSImpl; It's probably a newly created object. Because It is different from the document object given by ownerDocument as SAXSource.
        node.getUserData(...) // return NULL
    }
}

Document document = ...;
unmarshaller.setAdapter(new MyJaxbAdapter());
MyXMLObject object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new DOMSource(document), MyXMLObject.class).getValue();
```

But I can't get UserData inside XmlAdapter's unmarshal method. Is there any way to persist UserData?

---

Locator information is stored in the properties of Element as shown below.

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Element el = document.createElementNS(usedNamespaceUri, qName);
        // ...
        el.setUserData(
            ElementUserData.class.getName(),
            ElementUserData.builder()
               .lineNumber(locator.getLineNumber())
               .columnNumber(locator.getColumnNumber())
            .build(),
        null);
}
```

I need the Locator information (UserData) stored by the above code in the unmarshal of the XmlAdapter.
However, there is no userdata in the `node` passed as an argument to unmarshal .

---

Sample Code:

https://github.com/joseph-jclab/jaxb-question-01

Comment: Unable to understand what exactly is the issue. Can you recreate the issue with sample XML and POJO and show us what exactly you are expecting and whats the issue you are facing.

Comment: Your `location information` is coming from the fields in XML right? if so then how can you access them before `unmarshalling` the XML? Since you are calling the `new MyJaxbAdapter()` before `unmarshalling` there isn't a way to know what information it will have. I believe the best option is to use the `afterUnmarshall` method in this case you can do whatever you want after unmarshalling. I will provide an example for the same if required.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 My point is to keep the UserData object of the Element. Added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is something you are looking for but providing it as a reference so you might get some idea to proceed further:

Sample XML:

```
<root>
    <name>Batman</name>
    <year>2008</year>
</root>
```

Root.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    private String name;
    private String year;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomAdapter.class)
    private String after;

    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller m, Object parent) {
        after = name;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Within Unmarshal : " + v);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Within Marshal : " + v);
        return null;
    }
}
```

SampleMain.class:

```
public class SampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class).createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
        final Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Root.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(root.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Root(name=Batman, year=2008, after=Batman)
Within Marshal : Batman
<root>
   <name>Batman</name>
   <year>2008</year>
</root>
```